# Can't use date and time varaible in the string on out-file PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

Im trying to add the date and time as part of the name of an output file, but trows me an error

```
$now = (get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss).ToString()
...
Some operations
...
Out-File "E:\Activa\sslog_$now.log"
```

Error:

```
Out-File : The given path's format is not supported.
At E:\Activa\GetLast30.ps1:8 char:18
+ },'SkipUntil') | Out-File "E:\Activa\sslog_$now.log"

Any Ideas of what can I do?
```

Comment: Are there colons in the timestamp? Those are reserved for drive letters.

Comment: That was it brother, Thanks

Comment: @vonPryz post a proper answer :)